# What options are there for the CHKDSK on cmd?

Tags: cmd

Looking for good properties to add so I can perform a very in-depth disk check on all drives overnight and fix any errors.

Comment: What's so hard to understand about `chkdsk /?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal deep dive for Chkdsk is:

```
chkdsk c: /R /B
```

It will take a LONG LONG TIME to complete. So be preapred. Like.. maybe a day on a slow system.

Good luck !